# Problems testing simple random behaviour in rspec

Tags: ruby, rspec

Im having a bit of trouble testing some random behaviour in rspec. I have a method on a class that should change one of the classes instance variables if a randomly generated number equals 10. I cant find anyway to correctly test this with rspec.

Here is the code for the class

```
class Airport
    DEFAULT_CAPACITY = 20
    attr_reader :landed_planes, :capacity
    attr_accessor :weather

    def initialize(capacity=DEFAULT_CAPACITY,weather = "clear")
        @landed_planes = []
        @capacity = capacity
        @weather = weather
    end

    def stormy
        if rand(10) == 10 then @weather = "stormy" end
    end
end
```

does anyone know of a way i could write  test for the stormy method?

Answer (score 1):

One option is start rspec with `rspec --seed 123` this will ensure that your random numbers are always predictable. But this will effect all   subsequent calls to rand, shuffle, sample and so on.

Another way is to change your class to inject the randnumber generator:

```
class Airport
  DEFAULT_CAPACITY = 20
  attr_reader :landed_planes, :capacity
  attr_accessor :weather

  def initialize(capacity=DEFAULT_CAPACITY,weather = "clear", randomizer = ->(n) { rand(n)})
    @landed_planes = []
    @capacity = capacity
    @weather = weather
    @randomizer = randomizer 
  end

  def stormy
    if @randomizer.call(10) == 10 then @weather = "stormy" end
  end

end
```